# How to bind Gradient color in collection view

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I have to bind gradient colors in a collection view in a grid.
i have tried with xmal.cs side but it doesnot working.

```
    foreach(var item in abc)
                {
                    if ((item.index % 2) == 0)
                    {
                        GradientStopCollection gradientStops = new GradientStopCollection();
                        gradientStops.Add(new GradientStop() { Color = Color.FromHex("#840CA3"), Offset = (float)0.1 });
                        gradientStops.Add(new GradientStop() { Color = Color.FromHex("#F4B6BF"), Offset = (float)1.0 });
                        LinearGradientBrush linearGradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush()
                        {
                            EndPoint = new Point(0, 1),
                            GradientStops = gradientStops
                        };
                        item.BackgroundColor = linearGradientBrush;
    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GradientStopCollection gradientStops = new GradientStopCollection();
                        gradientStops.Add(new GradientStop() { Color = Color.FromHex("#A30C42"), Offset = (float)0.1 });
                        gradientStops.Add(new GradientStop() { Color = Color.FromHex("#F4B6BF"), Offset = (float)1.0 });
                        LinearGradientBrush linearGradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush()
                        {
                            EndPoint = new Point(0, 1),
                            GradientStops = gradientStops
                        };
                        item.BackgroundColor = linearGradientBrush;
                    }
                }
MycollectionView.itemsource = abc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:
You need Background, not Background Color.

Actually, what you need to do is:

Avoid this terrible design. You need to use binding, and instead of adding VisualElements, you need to be using DataTriggers, Styles and ItemTemplates.

You manipulate the data of your models. You should not iterate and assign individualy the color of your visual elements.

Spend few days to learn how to design your app properly, and it will save you years of working on problems.